# isolating arrays in byte arrays received in different times

Tags: c#

I am receiving a Bytes array every second from a source in my winform application via Uart. lets say it is something like below. 99,98 marks the start of a new packet. Each packet is of variable length but it always starts with this 99,98 id. I want to copy the individual packet into a receivedBuffer and then process them individually

second 1:
{56,42,43,76,125,56,34,234,12,3,5,76,8,0,**99**,**98**,234,56,211,122,22,4,7,89,76,64,12,3,5,**99**,**98**,0,6,125}

second2:

{6,125,56,34,234,12}

So inabove example in second 1 I receive first some garbage value, then 1 full packet and other partial packet. and in second 2 I receive the remaining of 2nd packet

(ps: packet 1 is 99,98,234,56,211,122,22,4,7,89,76,64,12,3,5)
a packet continues until u receive a 99,98 id bytes

Comment: How do we know that second 2 contains the entirety of the remainder of the 2nd packet? If, in second 3, we receieved `{22,99,98,...}` would that be valid, and in fact 22 be the last byte for the 2nd packet?

Comment: yes u r right. a packet continues until u get a 99, 98 id bytes

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a protocol difficult to handle: you can only rely on a "begin of packet" marker, you don't have a "packet length" nor "end of packet" marker.

So, reasonably, what you can do is:

- start with an empty array / memoryStream
- every time you get some bytes, add them the the array
- parse the new array content looking for "beging of packet" marker. if you find two (or more) of them, extract bytes included between them, and remove all bytes preceding last "begin of packet" found
- wait for next bytes

Note that you aren't able to understand when last packet is completed just parsing received bytes.